# Pass a private variable to another private fuction in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my own Stopwatch, but I'm having some troubles, on how to stop it, since the button is private, and i can't access it from the stop button.

This is my Clock class:

```
public class initClock {
    int h;
    int m;
    int s;

    public initClock(int h1, int m1, int s1){
        h = h1;
        m = m1;
        s = s1;
    }
}
```

This is my Stopwatch class:

```
public class Stopwatch {
    JTextField upField;
    int flag;
    initClock clock = new initClock(0,0,0);
    Timer runTime = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            if(clock.s == 60){
                clock.m++;
                clock.s = 0;
            }else if(clock.m == 60){
                clock.h++;
                clock.m=0;
            }
            clock.s++;
            upField.setText(clock.h + ":" + clock.m + ":" + clock.s);
        }
    };

    public Stopwatch(JTextField field){
        upField = field;
    }
}
```

And this is how i start it when i press the button:

```
private void bStart1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
 Stopwatch clock1 = new Stopwatch(tfStopwatch1);
 clock1.runTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(clock1.task, 1000, 1000);}
```

Any idea on how to make it stop ?

Something like:

```
private void bStop1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
  getClockFromStart().cancel();}
```

Thx =D

Comment: `clock1` isn't private - it's local to the function. Unless you are talking about something else, in which case you need to highlight it better

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, I'm trying to access clock1 on bStop1ActionPerformed, so I can stop the clock when the button is clicked.

Comment: Declare `clock1` outside of the `bStart1ActionPerformed` method so you'll be able to access it from outside of the `bStart1ActionPerformed` method, allowing you to call `cancel()` from other methods.

Comment: Just cancel the timer (`runTime`). But there are a couple of major drawbacks in your code. First, the timer task is not guaranteed to be called at _exactly_ 1000 ms intervals every time; therefore, your stopwatch could be out. Secondly, you should be using `System.nanotime()` which is not affected by people changing the system clock.

Comment: Klitos, how can i cancel the runTime, if i cant access it =/ ? I will look more about your suggestion and how to implement it, thank-you!

Comment: Make clock1 an instance variable of whatever class the `bStart1ActionPerformed()` and `bStop1ActionPerformed()` methods are in, instead of having it a local variable in `bStart1ActionPerformed()`.